# Is there any way to loop through different id and response json at once (using for loop or for each) and console.log(json key:value pair)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, foreach, click

I want button with different id(or class="respond") and button with common id (#resButt) which is on popup) clicked at a same time and do ajaxResponse() for all id's...

Comment: in short you want to click all button which has class `respond` ?

Comment: yes,  I want to click, all at the same (on load or after document ready) which has class respond. and all will open popup where there is button with id called #resButt . it should also clicked at the same time and do ajaxResonse() function to get me JSON: KEY:VALUE PAIR

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
function ajaxResponse() {
  alert('This triggers the ajaxResponse function');
}

$('.respond').click(function(e){
  console.log(e.target.id);
  $('#respButt').parent().show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="respond" href="#inline_content" id="52273">Respond</a>
<a class="respond" href="#inline_content" id="52270">Respond</a>
<a class="respond" href="#inline_content" id="52256">Respond</a>

<div style="display:none;border:1px solid black;background: lightgreen">
<p>Form goes here</p>
<button id="respButt" name="respBtn" onclick="ajaxResponse()">Send My Response</button>
</div>
```

You can use JQuery to essentially add an onclick event to each element of class "respond", which in this case will log its id to the console and open the div containing the button and form. If you need the button to be part of the form, just change this line:

```
$('#respButt').parent().show();
```

to include the corrent number of "parent()"s.

Hope this helps.

Comment: great! thanks for your suggestion. you are closer to 75%. when click on button with class "respond" it will open pop up form where "respButt" id with the button is there. when click on it will do ajaxResponse() and get me JSON key:value for different id's that are with class "respond" at once ( on load or on document ready)

Comment: Updated my answer to include this change.

Comment: i used your code. but it only shows form for only one id (that means i should have to click button one by one and get the ajaxresponse). But,i want to click all respond button all at the same time and also #resButt to response ajax for all id that are clicked same time

Comment: $('.respond').each(function(e){$(this).trigger('click');});} this shows all id's of the button. but i want ajaxresponse(); for all id's needed on this click. (it will show all ajaxresponse() for all button click (JSON-KEY:VALUE PAIR))

Answer (score 0):

```js
 function ajaxResponse() {
      alert('This triggers the ajaxResponse function');
            
     $('.respond').each(function(e){
     
      $(this).trigger('click');
      });

    }

    $('.respond').click(function(e){
       alert(e.target.id);
    });
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <a class="respond" href="#inline_content" id="52273">Respond</a>
    <a class="respond" href="#inline_content" id="52270">Respond</a>
    <a class="respond" href="#inline_content" id="52256">Respond</a>

    <div style="border:1px solid black;background: lightgreen">
    <p>Form goes here</p>
    <button id="respButt" name="respBtn" onclick="ajaxResponse()">Send My Response</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: $('.respond').each(function(e){$(this).trigger('click');});} this shows all id's of the button. but i want ajaxresponse(); for all id's needed on this click. (it will show all ajaxresponse() for all button click (JSON-KEY:VALUE PAIR))

Comment: It is confusing, when your `ajaxresponse()` called, you want all button's id ?

Comment: see concept is: with that code, we can get all button id, and every button clicked there is one popup, which will open and in that popup there is another button called #resButt (same id for all button that is clicked ) which is used to get ajaxresponse() for id.